# Upgrade steps for Sitecore 10

Tags: upgrade

I am looking for upgrade steps for Sitecore 10.
We are looking at upgrading from Sitecore 9 to 10.

Looks like dev site doesn't have any
steps yet.

Comment: The upgrade guide is found on the download page: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/100/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_100.aspx

Comment: Upgrade instructions are provided by Sitecore. Any answer here would simply be recycling the same information. If you have a specific problem during the upgrade, please post that question with detailed information about the problem and what you have done to resolve it so far. The question as worded is outside of the scope of SSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Sitecore 10 here -

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/100/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_100.aspx

See in below image it shows upgrade package from Sitecore 9-Sitecore 10

[image]

And in below image, you can find upgrade guide as well -

[image]